Which language will be the Japanese retail version of TBOI: Repentance?
There's a Japanese version of The Binding of Isaac: Repentance published by Pikii, and it's available for way less money than the original one:

I need to know if the game will have English localization and if possibile English trophies if I play it on a EU PS4.
Any info about that? I think it's essentially the same game.

I found on Amazon a review from someone saying its in English (albeit for the switch version: https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R37DQYA5QCABUL/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0B691973Z)

@TimmyJim cool, so half of the question is solved :)

you know that in the remote possibility an new DLC comes out you will have to somehow buy it from the Japanese store, right? Because that happened to many EU player that bought the NTSC physical version of Afterbirth only to be "scammed" later when Repentance was made (with the added bonus of the physical EU version of the game also being incompatible with the original EU dlc due to different distribution companies)

@Ꮢedacted I'm aware of that, but I remember that McMillen said that Repentance was the last DLC, that's why I waited to buy a physical copy

@pinckerman true, but I have a vague memory of Afterbirth "being the last big dlc" too. Alas, you should be able to still download updates even if the game is from another region, at least on switch.

This game review/unboxing video on Youtube states that the game includes English text.
During the review the author cycles the available languages: you can see Japanese, Korean, Chinese and English. This is coherent with the product description on Playasia.

Multiple reddit sources like this one seem to confirm that the English localization is included.

I will also include this one because reason that may or may not be related to thanking Nicalis for the awesome-not EU/US release, including scamming people who owned the previous HeadsUP EU version of Afterbirth by making it incompatible with their Repentance DLC on launch...


That's good, but what about trophy list?

@pinckerman I will try to get more info about that. I THINK trophies favor the system language at installation time.

Since you never answered, I can confirm that the game has English localization, too, but trophies are in Japanese, and I don't know if it's possible to change that.
